# Set Default Value to ng-bind in HTML

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init, ng-bind

I'd like to set a default value to scope, which is picked up by ng-bind. I am doing this like:

```
<button>Show <span data-ng-bind="data.text" data-ng-init="data.text = 'All';"></span> Names</button>
```

In this example, the span is set to innerHTML = 'All' when the page loads.

However, I was hoping there might be a way to do this without requiring the use of ng-init, maybe something like:

```
<button>Show <span data-ng-bind="data.text = 'All';"></span> Names</button>
```

Comment: `{{data.text || "All"}}` (if you dont have an issue moving away from `ng-bind`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your controller:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.text = "All";
```

Your markup:

```
<button>Show <span data-ng-bind="data.text"></span> Names</button>
```

Or, if you want to skip the controller code (courtesy of Kohjah Breese' comment):

```
    <button>Show <span data-ng-bind="data.text || 'All'"></span> Names</button>
```

Presumably there will be some code elsewhere in your controller that will toggle this value, but for the purposes of initializing, that should do.

EDIT: Alternately, as tymeJV points out in the comments (ng-cloak added so {{}} syntax doesn't display to users):

```
<button>Show <span ng-cloak>{{data.text || "All"}}</span> Names</button>
```

Comment: This is also working, which the kind of thing I am looking for: <span data-ng-bind="data.text || 'All'"></span>

Comment: For what it's worth, the codeschool.com beginning course (which is excellent, and I don't get paid to say that, etc.) uses `this` instead of `$scope`, but I'm guessing it's fairly standard practice to do so. Perhaps they use it in the next-level course

Answer (score 5):

The `||` operator works also in `ngBind` like in pure JavaScript:

```
<span ng-bind="myVariable || 'My default value'"></span>
```

This outputs `myVariable` if the variable is filled, otherwise the alternative `'My default value'` is used.

Answer (score 2):

from [angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) :

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat [...] Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope.

So i guess initializing data.text in your controller is fine for angularjs